Predicate logic model: Which of the models is true given this formula
This question comes from the book Logic in Computer Science written by Michael Huth a.e. and page 163.
Consider the sentence $\varphi$ defined as:
$$
\varphi \equiv \forall x \exists y \exists z (P(x, y) \land P(z,y) \land (P(x, z) \rightarrow P(z, x))).
$$
Which of the following models satisfies $\varphi$?
(a) The model $M$ consists of the set of natural numbers with $P^M$ defined as:
$$
P^M = \{(m, n) \mid m < n\}.
$$
(b) The model $M'$ consists of the set of natural numbers with $P^{M'}$ defined as:
$$
P^{M'} = \{(m, 2 \cdot m) \mid m \text{ is a natural number}\}.
$$
(c) The model $M''$ consists of the set of natural numbers with $P^{M''}$ defined as:
$$
P^{M''} = \{(m, n) \mid m < n + 1\}.
$$
Sadly there is no solutions for all the questions so I am left to think whether I did correct or not so I'd appreciate it if someone can verify for me.
I said the answer is (b).
(a) says for x's there exists a y such that x<y and there exists a y and z such that z<y and for all x's there exists a z such z<x. Basically that for all natural numbers there are two numbers greate which is true. If that is true for all x's there exists a y such x>y. This is false because because given 1 we have no numbers smaller in our set of numbers.
T -> F= F
(b) For all x there exists a y such that $y=2*z \geq 1$ which is true. And there exists a y & z such that $y=2*z \geq 1$ whcih is true. And for all x there exists a z such that $x=2*z\geq 1$. This is false. Because Given x=3. We get y=6. Then the only number that can satify the second statement is if z=3 and 3 is not divisble by 2. F -> Anything = True.
(c) This ends up being false as well.
My question: Have I done right? If not, what did I do wrong?
